# Bash/OSX script to run commands in 2 Terminal/iTerm tabs?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, iterm

To run my node server proxy and then my project in Gulp Browsersync, every time i need to run node server in one tab, open a tab in the same directory and run Gulp.

I'm not sure if the second tab is even needed, if there's a way to simply run Node Server in the background, and then issue "gulp" right there.

I was trying to find a way to script this project,to switch to the directory, run the node server, and then run gulp. Either with bash or applescript/bash.

I can write bash scripts myself for all parts except the need to run the 2 processes. That's the part that has me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

In a shell script, you can ask for commands to be started in the background by appending `&`, for example, inferring plausible names from your question:

```
./node &
./gulp &
```

This could be a bit messy if one of the commands, not expecting to run in the background, writes to its output. In this case, I would recommend redirecting output to oblivion (`&>/dev/null`) or, if the output is relevant, scripting with GNU screen.